# How is it possible that not calling OracleDataReader.Read() still returns a row?

Tags: vb.net, oracle11g, odp.net

When I upgraded to use OracleManagedDataAccess provider, the code below did not work,  I was baffled because the source code has never change since inception, and its on production server.

I understand why it does not work, as it not calling OracleDataReader.Read()

So, is this a bug that has been indentified by Oracle? Could you point to documentation if yes? Before project was simply referencing 4.112.4.0, now I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

Anyone else find this interesting?

```
Public Function GeCount(ByVal value As Integer) As Integer

            Dim pCount As New PageCount

            Using conn As OracleConnection = New OracleConnection(connString)

                'conn.Open()

                Using cmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand()

                    cmd.Connection = conn

                    pCount.PageCnt = 0

                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM dual"



                    cmd.Connection.Open()

                    Using rdr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

                        If rdr.HasRows Then

                            If Not rdr.IsDBNull(0) Then pCount.PageCnt = CInt(CInt(rdr.GetDecimal(0)) / pSize)

                        End If

                    End Using

                    cmd.Connection.Close()

                    cmd.Dispose()

                End Using



                conn.Dispose()

            End Using



            Return pCount

        End Function
```

Any ideas?

### EDIT

After switching to use Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll, I get this error, which is expected, but it was working before with a reference to Oracle Data Access Client 4.112.4.0

```
- <Fault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/envelope/none">
- <Code>
  <Value>Receiver</Value> 
- <Subcode>
  <Value xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</Value> 
  </Subcode>
  </Code>
- <Reason>
  <Text xml:lang="en-US">Invalid attempt to read when no data is present</Text> 
  </Reason>
- <Detail>
- <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HelpLink i:nil="true" /> 
  <InnerException i:nil="true" /> 
  <Message>Invalid attempt to read when no data is present</Message> 
  <StackTrace>at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.IsDBNull(Int32 i) at WcfRestService1.WcfRestService1.SiteEDocXRefRepository.GetSiteEDocCount(Int32 site_id) at WcfRestService1.WcfRestService1.EDocSvc.GetCntCollectionXRefSiteEDoc(String site_id) at SyncInvokeGetCntCollectionXRefSiteEDoc(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace> 
  <Type>System.InvalidOperationException</Type> 
  </ExceptionDetail>
  </Detail>
  </Fault>
```

Comment: Not calling something cannot return anything. It's programming. If you did not assign a result of some function to a variable, your environment will not create some variable and assign result of some random function to it. Please explain what you meant.

Comment: No need to belittle, see edited post for clarification.

Comment: I would say that it was a bug in the older version of the data access client. The attempts to use the `rdr` object before issuing the Read statement should cause an exception. The easiest fix would be to replace the condition from `rdr.HasRows` to `rdr.Read`. Have you looked at the list of fixes each intermediate version to see if any of them contains something about this?

Comment: @martin Do you know where Oracle keeps documents containing fixes?

Comment: I just searched for ["Oracle DataAccess Client" changelog site:docs.oracle.com] and got back a few hits. I'm not sure which version might've fixed the issue, though. I'm not very familiar with Oracle at all.

Comment: @martin thanks!, I'll will try to find something.